# Faster bitwise AND operation on byte slices

Tags: go, assembly, bit-manipulation, slice

I'd like to perform bitwise AND on every column of a byte matrix, which is stored in a `[][]byte` in golang. I created a [repo](https://github.com/shenwei356/bench/tree/main/bitwise-and-on-byte-slices) with runnable test code.

It can be simplified as a bitwise AND operation on two byte-slice of equal length. The simplest way is using `for` loop to handle every pair of bytes.

```golang
func and(x, y []byte) []byte {
    z := make([]byte, lenght(x))
    for i:= 0; i < len(x); i++ {
        z[i] = x[i] & y[i]
    }
    return z
}
```

However, it's very slow for long slices. A faster way is to unroll the `for` loop (check the [benchmark result](https://github.com/shenwei356/bench/tree/main/bitwise-and-on-byte-slices))

```
BenchmarkLoop-16                   14467             84265 ns/op
BenchmarkUnrollLoop-16             17668             67550 ns/op
```

Any faster way? Go assembly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you benchmarking? Shouldn't `make(...)` call be outside of the benchmark loop?

Comment: SIMD is very good for bitwise-AND of two contiguous chunks of memory, into a 3rd.  It should run at STREAM Triad speed on your machine, or faster if the data fits in cache instead of having to come from main memory.  If Go doesn't auto-vectorize, then there's a lot of room to gain from using some way of getting SIMD instructions.

Comment: @Ruslan, which line? https://github.com/shenwei356/bench/blob/main/bitwise-and-on-byte-slices/test_test.go#L60 ? There's no `make` inside the benchmark loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes Right but there's no way to directly call SMID instructions 
 in Go, have to write go assembly :( which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: This is a pretty simple problem to auto-vectorize; a compiler would just have to check whether the output slice overlapped either input.  If your compiler doesn't auto-vectorize, your options are: use a different compiler (possible for a different language via a foreign-function interface), use assembly, or have your code run slow.  Or maybe have your code at best work 8 bytes at a time, instead of 16 or 32, if Go lets you type-pun your pointer/slice types to use 64-bit chunks for the multiple-of-8 parts of the byte slices.  I don't know Go.

Comment: @PeterCorder  The Go compiler does not auto-vectorise and calling FFI functions incurs a costly overhead.  Type punning is somewhat possible but frowned upon.  The best choice is write the relevant code in Go-style assembly.  You can have the C compiler do that for you and then just copy-edit the calling convention.

Comment: Not enough information to answer this. You need to example example data, even if its dummy data

Comment: I found a good implementation, which turns every 8 bytes into `uint64`s and computes AND on these numbers.  It's 3X faster than the canonical `for` loop way . https://github.com/grailbio/base/blob/master/simd/and_amd64.go#L32

Answer (score 2):

I write a [go assembly implementation](https://github.com/shenwei356/pand) using AVX2 instructions after two days of (go) assembly learning.

The performance is good, `10X` of simple loop version. While optimizations for compatibility and performance are still needed. Suggestions and PRs are welcome.

Note: code and benchmark results are updated.

I appreciate @PeterCordes for many valuable suggestions.

```
#include "textflag.h"

// func AND(x []byte, y []byte)
// Requires: AVX
TEXT ·AND(SB), NOSPLIT|NOPTR, $0-48
    // pointer of x
    MOVQ x_base+0(FP), AX

    // length of x
    MOVQ x_len+8(FP), CX

    // pointer of y
    MOVQ y_base+24(FP), DX

    // --------------------------------------------
    // end address of x, will not change: p + n
    MOVQ AX, BX
    ADDQ CX, BX

    // end address for loop
    // n <= 8, jump to tail
    CMPQ CX, $0x00000008
    JLE  tail

    // n < 16, jump to loop8
    CMPQ CX, $0x00000010
    JL   loop8_start

    // n < 32, jump to loop16
    CMPQ CX, $0x00000020
    JL   loop16_start

    // --------------------------------------------
    // end address for loop32
    MOVQ BX, CX
    SUBQ $0x0000001f, CX

loop32:
    // compute x & y, and save value to x
    VMOVDQU (AX), Y0
    VANDPS  (DX), Y0, Y0
    VMOVDQU Y0, (AX)

    // move pointer
    ADDQ $0x00000020, AX
    ADDQ $0x00000020, DX
    CMPQ AX, CX
    JL   loop32

    // n <= 8, jump to tail
    MOVQ BX, CX
    SUBQ AX, CX
    CMPQ CX, $0x00000008
    JLE  tail

    // n < 16, jump to loop8
    CMPQ CX, $0x00000010
    JL   loop8_start

    // --------------------------------------------
loop16_start:
    // end address for loop16
    MOVQ BX, CX
    SUBQ $0x0000000f, CX

loop16:
    // compute x & y, and save value to x
    VMOVDQU (AX), X0
    VANDPS  (DX), X0, X0
    VMOVDQU X0, (AX)

    // move pointer
    ADDQ $0x00000010, AX
    ADDQ $0x00000010, DX
    CMPQ AX, CX
    JL   loop16

    // n <= 8, jump to tail
    MOVQ BX, CX
    SUBQ AX, CX
    CMPQ CX, $0x00000008
    JLE  tail

    // --------------------------------------------
loop8_start:
    // end address for loop8
    MOVQ BX, CX
    SUBQ $0x00000007, CX

loop8:
    // compute x & y, and save value to x
    MOVQ (AX), BX
    ANDQ (DX), BX
    MOVQ BX, (AX)

    // move pointer
    ADDQ $0x00000008, AX
    ADDQ $0x00000008, DX
    CMPQ AX, CX
    JL   loop8

    // --------------------------------------------
tail:
    // left elements (<=8)
    MOVQ (AX), BX
    ANDQ (DX), BX
    MOVQ BX, (AX)
    RET
```

Benchmark result:

```
test                       data-size        time
-------------------        ---------        -----------
BenchmarkGrailbio          8.00_B           4.654 ns/op
BenchmarkGoAsm             8.00_B           4.824 ns/op
BenchmarkUnrollLoop        8.00_B           6.851 ns/op
BenchmarkLoop              8.00_B           8.683 ns/op

BenchmarkGrailbio          16.00_B          5.363 ns/op
BenchmarkGoAsm             16.00_B          6.369 ns/op
BenchmarkUnrollLoop        16.00_B          10.47 ns/op
BenchmarkLoop              16.00_B          13.48 ns/op

BenchmarkGoAsm             32.00_B          6.079 ns/op
BenchmarkGrailbio          32.00_B          6.497 ns/op
BenchmarkUnrollLoop        32.00_B          17.46 ns/op
BenchmarkLoop              32.00_B          21.09 ns/op

BenchmarkGoAsm             128.00_B         10.52 ns/op
BenchmarkGrailbio          128.00_B         14.40 ns/op
BenchmarkUnrollLoop        128.00_B         56.97 ns/op
BenchmarkLoop              128.00_B         80.12 ns/op

BenchmarkGoAsm             256.00_B         15.48 ns/op
BenchmarkGrailbio          256.00_B         23.76 ns/op
BenchmarkUnrollLoop        256.00_B         110.8 ns/op
BenchmarkLoop              256.00_B         147.5 ns/op

BenchmarkGoAsm             1.00_KB          47.16 ns/op
BenchmarkGrailbio          1.00_KB          87.75 ns/op
BenchmarkUnrollLoop        1.00_KB          443.1 ns/op
BenchmarkLoop              1.00_KB          540.5 ns/op

BenchmarkGoAsm             16.00_KB         751.6 ns/op
BenchmarkGrailbio          16.00_KB         1342 ns/op
BenchmarkUnrollLoop        16.00_KB         7007 ns/op
BenchmarkLoop              16.00_KB         8623 ns/op
```

Comment: You can save instructions / uops by using a loop structure like `do{}while(ptr < endp)`, with a `cmp / jb` at the bottom involving AX or DX.  [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926).  You'd still need a check in case the vector loop should run 0 times, but that check can be outside the loop.  (And you'd want an LEA to compute `end_pointer = p + size - 0x1f` in a register instead of using CX as a down-counter).  If you aren't memory bottlenecked, this could even make your loop run faster, else just more hyperthreading friendly.

Comment: You don't need to xor-zero Y0 before the first load.  `VMOVAPD (AX), Y0` overwrites Y0 without caring about the previous value.  Also, I'd recommend `vmovdqa` SIMD-integer load/store instructions, not `vmovapd` (packed-double).  It won't actually matter on most CPUs, I don't think.  If you want, you could avoid AVX2 by only using `vmovaps` (or pd) and `vandps`.

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes , I changed to code following all your suggestions,  thank you so much!  Should I replace the code in the answer or append a new version? Anyway, it's available on the github.

Comment: I'd recommend just updating the code.  You could mention that the old version is still there in the edit history, especially if you want include a separate benchmark line for it.

Comment: @PeterCordes , `vmovdqu` instead of `vmovdqa` should be used, because data may not be aligned, at least for Go slice :P :( I find this bug for nearly one whole day... :(

Comment: Well yeah, if your data isn't guaranteed to be aligned, then you wouldn't want to use misalignment-detecting loads; letting the hardware handle possibly misaligned loads/stores is generally fine.  Fortunately for you, AVX memory source operands for other instructions (like `vpand`) don't require alignment.

Comment: I found `VPAND` bring slightly higher performance than `VANDPS`.  And the package supports AVX512 now. Thank you @PeterCordes and @fuz !